# How do I avoid pointer invalidation in my insert function?

Tags: c++

In my data structures course, we are creating a basic vector class. In my header, there is a member function for inserting new values into the vector. If the capacity of my vector is big enough for the insertion of one value, the program runs fine. However, if the vector needs to grow, I run into pointer errors. After hours of trying to figure out what was happening, I believe that I'm running into a problem with invalidating iterators.

Here are my insert function, and reserve function:

```
// Insert "item" before "pos", and return iterator referencing "item"

iterator insert (iterator pos, const T& item)
{

if (m_size ==  m_capacity)
  {
  reserve(m_capacity * 2);
  }

T * endOfArray = (end());

while (endOfArray != pos)
  {
  *(endOfArray) = *(endOfArray - 1);
  --endOfArray;
  }
++m_size;
*pos = item;

return (pos);
}

void reserve (size_t space) {
if (space < m_capacity)
  {
  return;
  }

T *temp_array = new T[space]; 

std::copy(begin(), end(), temp_array);
m_array = new T[space];
std::copy(temp_array, (temp_array + m_size), m_array);
m_capacity = space;
delete [] temp_array;
}
```

As you can see, if the insert function calls to have the capacity of the vector increased, then the "pos" iterator invalidates. How can I get around this problem?

Comment: what error exactly do you see?  also please post the code of reserve and end.

Comment: You got your answer by Peter Alexander. Just one remark about reserve function. You don't need temporary buffer and double copying. You can just create new buffer, copy data, and set m_array to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the `pos` iterator into an index instead, and use that.

```
size_t index = pos - begin();
// do resize
pos = begin() + index;
```

If you're worried about iterators invalidating in general, don't. It's unavoidable, at least in this style of dynamic array, and `std::vector` works exactly the same.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, Peter. Are you saying that instead of iterating through the Array, I should use indexing?

Comment: @user465367: You could do this, or you could just "store" the iterator as an index before reallocation and then "restore" it to an iterator before performing the actual insertion. Whatever you prefer.

Comment: Sir, you are a Saint. Thank you very much.